# jQuery get specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have a div with few classes in no specific order.

```
<div class="whatever styledark myclass"></div>
```

I'm interested in the styledark class. This can be styledark, stylewhite, stylered.... I want to get this class name no matter what color comes after the word style.  The question is, when i click on the div, how i do i alert this class name that start with the word style disregarding other classes in the div. The classes are in no specific order.

Comment: It's not impossible, but it's clumsy. Moreover, it's going to be *very* slow. Can you not add another class to the attribute?

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: @lonesomeday I want to know what color class the div has. I don't see a way around it unless you can recommended one.

Comment: @felix, User builds a form using the tools provided, when user comes back to edit the form, the editing select box of available styles should highlight the current style of the form. The only way to know the current style color of the form is to get the class name that starts with style

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a great question. Although it can be done using many of the answers mentioned here, this is a little awkward and costly performance wise. The way i would recommend you do it is put the style class last, that way with only one line of code you can output the class name you are after.

```
$('element').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
```

Comment: @Hussein How about this: `$('element').attr('class').split(' ').filter('myclass')`

Comment: @SIFE what is myclass ?? full class name is unknown. OP is after the class name that starts with style.

Comment: @Hussein myclass refer to class he looking for it.

Comment: @hussein. Thanks for the recommendation. This makes allot of sense. I just need to figure out my code to see how to place this style class last.

Comment: @SIFE, i'm not looking for myclass. Otherwise i wouldn't have asked this question if class name is known.

Comment: @Pinkie Sorry, I miss understood you, I thought you want to extract a class.

Comment: it sounds pretty nasty to be bound to use conventions like "put the style class last".Personally I prefer a more bullet-proof way of solving problem + I don't think that this "line of code" is in a way more efficient than other answers (it still uses a css selector and still accesses the "class" attribute).

Comment: @gion_13 I can't make out what you mean by your comment. I would like to see your alternative way of solving this rather thing posting a comment that doesn't help OP in anyway.

Comment: @Hussein sry, I didn't want to offend you in any way.If you were to scroll down just a little bit, maybe you could see my "alternative way of solving this".I wasn't just making a comment not to help, I was just trying to state my own approach that is not less efficient and does not need to use any conventions.

Comment: @gion i didn't realize you posted an answer. All answers below are valid solutions. The solution i recommended however is at least 80% faster and only short line of code. http://jsperf.com/chooseclass. I don't understand what you meant in your comment above when you said this short line of code is not more efficient.  OP in his comments asked for alternative approach, and i provided hm with one.

Comment: But what if he wants to add classes later? It breaks your code. I'm with @gion_13 about this, even tough (surprise) I prefer my solution, or using a Regex like @Kai does.

Comment: I appreciate all your suggestions, Performance and Cross browser compatibility is very important to me. @hussein's solution worked great for this matter. I knew the way i had t wasn't the best way to do things. For now having the style class last is no issue for me and i will stick with this solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var style = this.className.split(/\s/).filter(function( cn ) {
        return cn.indexOf('style') === 0;
    });

    alert(style);
});
```

Note this code uses `Array.prototype.filter` and `.indexof()`, which is not available in old'ish browsers. To make this more generic, it would look like:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var name = '';

    $.each(this.className.split(/\s/), function( _, cn ) {
        if( cn.indexOf('style') === 0 ) { name = cn; return false; }
    });

    alert(name);
});
```

Comment: thanks @jandy, but it must be cross browser. Having explained my situation in the comment above in reply to felix, i wonder if this is the best way to go about what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @Pinkie: well, it actually is pretty much crossbrowser, except you're dealing with IE7 and below. However, I've added a more compatible version.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var c = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    for(var s in c)
        if(c[s].indexOf('style') == 0)
            alert(c[s]);
});
```

live example : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/rXkNy/1/

Answer (score 3):

I used to use the classList attribute, but unfortunately it seems that it's not in safari. :(
The following is what I came up with, but the RegExp may need just a little tweaking.

```
$('div.button').each(function() {
        $m =  this.className.match(/(^|\s)style\S+(\s|$)/);
    if($m) {
        $(this).bind('click', { colorName : $m[0] }, function(e) {
            alert(e.data.colorName);
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Found here:  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-how-to-pick-out-classes-that-start-with-a-particular-string

```
var icons = ["Star", "Plus", "Left", "Right", "Up", "Down"];

$("div.button").each(function() {
    var $dv = $(this);
    $.each(icons, function() {
        if ($dv.hasClass("icon" + this)) {
            $dv.append('<img src="Images/' + this + '.gif" alt="" />');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the list of class names in a variable called "classes":

```
classes = classes.split(" ");
for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++)
{
    var class = classes[i];
    if (class.indexOf("style") == 0)
    {
        alert(class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div[class]").click(function(e){
    $.each(this.className.split(/\s/), function(i, val) {
        if (/^style/.test(val)) {
            alert(val.substr(5));
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('element').attr("class").split(" ").filter(getStyleClass);

function getStyleClass(value) {
    return value.indexOf("style") > -1;
}
```

And to alert the 'style' class on a click, as you specified:

```
$('element').click(function()[
    var style_class = $(this).attr("class").split(" ").filter(getStyleClass);
    alert(style_class);
}
// include the same getStyleClass from above
```

**more depth:**

`$('element').attr("class").split(" ")` is a good start - it puts the classes in an array, but `.pop()` simply removes the last element of the array, and that does not solve the problem.

`.filter()` is a great solution because you can write a small function that decides which elements you want.

In our case we only want elements of the array that have 'style'. We can use `.indexOf()` to decide if the string contains "style" like this: `value.indexOf("style") > -1`.